# Zend application within zend application, route issues

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-application

So I have a Zend project, let's say project1 and another Zend project inside the source folder of project1, let's say project2.
Let the url of project1 be www.project1.com.

So when I access "www.project1.com/project2", it runs the default module, controller, action of project2. But if I do like "www.project1.com/project2/test/index/index", or access a route defined in project2 like "www.project1.com/project2/agb", the project1 application tries to map it on a route defined in project1 as "/:module/:controller/:action/:id/:page".

What I want to do is that if a url starts with "project1.com/project2", then no matter what, it should get to the project2 application. I can't use regex because ":module" is a variable, or at least I don't know how to do it.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: What's the reason behind of having two zend applications under the same public folder? This sounds to me like a horrible setup to begin with :-/

Comment: I want to build project2 as a portable zend application, which I could place on any server with as least configurations as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
Infact there was no problem at all.

The index.php for project2 needs to be in main directory since I am accessing the project with a directory url, i.e., "project1.com/project2" (no server alias). So all I had to do is to replace .htaccess from /public directory to project2 main directory and wola...!
It works